# How to highlight md-card or change the backgroud color of md-card in angular2

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have 4 md-cards. on selection (click) of the card i want to highlight the card or change the background of the card. can you please let me know how to achieve that

```
<div class="ui-g">
      <div class="ui-g-3"><md-card  [style.background]="'#fbeafc'"><md-card-content><h3>Component1</h3>
        </md-card-content></md-card></div>
    <div class="ui-g-3"><md-card  [style.background]="'#fbeafc'"><md-card-content><h3>Component2</h3>
        </md-card-content></md-card></div>
    <div class="ui-g-3"><md-card  [style.background]="'#fbeafc'"><md-card-content><h3>Component3</h3>
        </md-card-content></md-card></div>
     <div class="ui-g-3"><md-card  [style.background]="'#fbeafc'"><md-card-content><h3>Component4</h3>
        </md-card-content></md-card></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I have this Plunker https://embed.plnkr.co/GYWY2HxFz41tmiXswFNs/ , maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to do it is, change your code to the following

**Component**

```js
//declare a class member in component
private isSelected:string;

//in the component define a function
setColor(value){
  this.isSelected=value;
}
```

**Styles**

```css
//in css
.color1{
  background:#fbeafc
}

.color1{
  background:#fbeafc
}

.color1{
  background:#fbeafc
}

.color1{
  background:#fbeafc
}
```

**Template**

```html
<div class="ui-g">
  <div class="ui-g-3">
    <md-card  [class.color1]="isSelected === 'color1'" (click)="setColor('color1')">
      <md-card-content>
        <h3>Component1</h3>
      </md-card-content>
    </md-card>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-g-3">
    <md-card  [class.color2]="isSelected === 'color2'" (click)="setColor('color2')">
      <md-card-content>
        <h3>Component2</h3>
      </md-card-content>
    </md-card>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-g-3">
    <md-card  [class.color3]="isSelected === 'color3'" (click)="setColor('color3')">
      <md-card-content>
        <h3>Component3</h3>
      </md-card-content>
    </md-card>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-g-3">
    <md-card  [class.color4]="isSelected === 'color4'" (click)="setColor('color4')">
      <md-card-content>
        <h3>Component4</h3>
      </md-card-content>
    </md-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps. Please verify the code before using it. I Haven't tested it

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you work with the latest angular material and want to change background-color of your [card](https://material.angular.io/components/card/overview) for hover and clicked/active states: Maybe this lazy approach helps:

```
.mat-card:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.mat-card:active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

...and don't forget to define the 'onclick' attribute.

```
<mat-card (click)="yourFn()">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want multiple cards to be highlighted at the same time, you can maintain a flag array to keep track of which card is getting selected and deselected. Then, we can use `ngClass` to use the flags to set the background for each card.

Since all your cards are almost the same, I am using `*ngFor` to avoid code repetition.

html:

```
<div class="ui-g">
  <div class="ui-g-3" *ngFor="let x of [1, 2, 3, 4]; let i = index">
    <md-card  [ngClass]="{'highlight' : selected[i], 'not-highlight' : !selected[i]}"
              (click)="onSelect(i)">
      <md-card-content>
        <h3>Component {{x}}</h3>
      </md-card-content>
    </md-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

ts:

```
selected = [false, false, false, false];

onSelect(index){
  // console.log(index);
  this.selected[index] = !this.selected[index];
}
```

css:

```
.highlight{
  background: skyblue;
}

.not-highlight{
  background: #fbeafc;
}
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/6mNDUf9AMQC0XVMO2euq?p=preview)